# Mercurial clone command hangs on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mercurial

I am trying to clone a Mercurial repository onto a machine running Ubuntu. The same repository clone command works successfully on my Windows PC, but on the Ubuntu machine the clone command hangs. The last message it prints out is "adding changesets". The repository folder has been created, and it contains a .hg folder, with a 'store' folder beneath that. In 'store' there is a symbolic link called 'lock'.

With the --debug flag on, the output is:

```
sending capabilities command
destination directory: <repo-name>
query 1; heads
sending batch command
requesting all changes
sending getbundle command
adding changesets
```

I can't find anything on the web to explain this, so I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Start by cloning without updating by adding the `--noupdate` option.

Comment: You can also clone up to any revision you want. Clone to the first one and pull the remaining changesets.

Comment: "hg clone --noupdate <repository-name>" behaves just the same

Comment: Try a simple `hg init` to create your new repo, and pull some chagesets from the main repo.

Comment: You can try running it with --debug to get some more feedback on what's happening. How long did you let it run? Are the Windows and Ubuntu machines on the same network connection?

Comment: Thanks. I've put the debug output into the main question.

Comment: Does it hang if there is no symbolic link in the folder? What does the symbolic link point to?